# use wpml_post_language_details function other plugin based on $post->ID

Tags: posts, filters, hooks, plugin-wpml

I would like to use `wpml_post_language_details` function in other plugin based on `$post->ID` of WP.

WPML language plugin wants to use for fetching lang information.

I also wonder if i can use `apply_filters`. Word press is new to me.